# Error con materialize en proyecto de Aurelia

Tags: typescript, materialize, aurelia.io

Buen día,

Tengo un proyecto de .Net Core 2.1 al cual le instale AureliaJS. Siguiente al haber creado el proyecto seguí este manual para instalar materialize:

https://aurelia-ui-toolkits-1.gitbook.io/materialize-bridge-docs/

Pero tengo el problema que no puedo usar el select, al parecer es como si no se inicializara, les paso la información de los archivos

App.html

```
<template>
  <require from="materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"></require>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

App.ts

```
export class App {

  attached()
  {
    //Inicializar  los controles
    var element = document.querySelector("div.input-field select");
    M.FormSelect.init(element,{});
  }
}
```

main.js

```
 import { PLATFORM, Aurelia } from "aurelia-framework";
 import environment from './environment';
 import "materialize-css";

 export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
   aurelia.use
     .standardConfiguration()
     .feature('resources')
        .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-validation"))
     .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-materialize-bridge'), b => b.useAll());

   aurelia.use.developmentLogging(environment.debug ? 'debug' : 'warn');

   if (environment.testing) {
     aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-testing');
   }

   return aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
 }
```

Resultado visual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No hay combo, no hay errores en consola.

Alguna idea? y gracias :)